# Error while installing python-snappy

Tags: python, pip, cython, snappy

I'm basically trying to install a package that requires snappy compiled in c for speed. I have already downloaded and installed the required compiler from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=44266.

This https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZfK1.jpg is the error I'm getting.

I can't figure out why it's not able to get stdint.h. It should come with the compiler right?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar error seen in: https://github.com/FSX/misaka/issues/49

User solved the problem doing:

1. Download Visual C++ for Python from https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=44266
2. Copy stdint.h to installation path\VC\include

Comment: I copied the stdint.h into the include folder but it gives the same error. What gives?

Comment: Did you copied stdint.h to: **C:\Users\Raza\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\include** ?

Comment: Ah that did the trick. I copied it in ProgramFiles/...

Many thanks!